# Alpha, Bravo, Charlie, and Delta are playing in a tennis tournament.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

(a) If there are no ties at the end of the tournament, how many different rankings are possible for the four players?
(b) If all the players have the same skill, what is the probability that Charlie will be the winner of the tournament?

For (a) I think the answer is simply 4! since there are no ties.
For (b) since they all have the same skill the P(Charlie winning) is equally likely as any other player winning which I think is 1/4, but it seems to simple
Any ideas what could be the answer for (b)?

Comment: You are right. You have $4!$ possible rankings. If Charlie is winning, than you have $3!$ possible rankings for A,B and D at the remaining three positions. Thus P(Charlie winning)=$\frac{3!}{4!}=\frac{1}{4}$